# Is there any solution to the not authorized error?

Tags: sqlite, go

```
sqlite3, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./map.gpkg")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

_, err = sqlite3.Exec("select load_extension('mod_spatialite');")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
```

When I try to load spatialite extension into sqlite3, it returns a not authorized error, I don't know how to fix it.

```
panic: not authorized

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /Users/u/project/project/golang_project/pack/sql/main.go:42 +0x145
exit status 2
```

Comment: I've edited the question, could you please check it?

Comment: And what happens if you try loading it by hand with the sqlite command-line client?

Comment: I am using sqlite3 for the first time, sqlite3 is not installed on my machine, I use golang driver

Comment: OK, so you're saying you don't know if what you are trying to do with golang works at all and you don't have any plans to test that? Good luck, then

Comment: No, I installed sqlite3 and in the terminal
select load_extension('mod_spatialite'); Executing the command returns the following:

 no such function: load_extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register extension using Extensions field of SQLiteDriver:

```
sql.Register("sqlite3_TestExtensionsError",
    &sqlite3.SQLiteDriver{
        Extensions: []string{
            "foobar",
        },
    },
)
```

See this example: https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/blob/1157a4212dcb650962563f67cd405794e9115b45/sqlite3_load_extension_test.go#L15

Comment: I would reverse the order of the sentences so that your answer first addresses the question and then gives further pointers.

Comment: I ran the testing as advised, and the spatialite was successfully loaded!!

Comment: However, if you load a multipolygon type column through asText(), you get an empty array like [],[]

Answer (score 0):

```
sql.Register("sqlite3_with_extensions",
    &sqlite3.SQLiteDriver{
        Extensions: []string{
            "mod_spatialite",
        },
    })

db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3_with_extensions", "./map.gpkg")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
```

i changed code as above and my code working fine.